# Ordering items from a model in a list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC 4 and I'm trying to figure out how to order a list that is being created by reading in from a model.

Here is the model code:

```
public class Files
{
    [Key]
    public int File_id { get; set; }
    public string Original_file_name { get; set; }
    public string Current_file_name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string File_path { get; set; }
    public string File_type { get; set; }
    public string File_status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiry_date { get; set; }
    //public int Uploaded_by { get; set; }
    //public DateTime Uploaded_on { get; set; }
}

public class FilesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Files> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller code that creates the list:

```
return View(db.Files.ToList());
```

Lastly the html that writes it to screen:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Original_file_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Current_file_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.File_type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.File_status)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Expiry_date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.File_id }) |
        <!--@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", new { id=item.File_id }) |-->
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.File_id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Order By File Name Ascending:**

```
db.Files.OrderBy(file => file.Original_file_name).ToList();
```

**Order By File Name Descening:**

```
db.Files.OrderByDescending(file => file.Original_file_name).ToList();
```

**Multiple Order By:**

```
db.Files.OrderBy(file => file.Original_file_name).ThenBy(file => file.Expiry_date).ToList();
```

You can also refer: [**MSDN: LINQ Sorting Operations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb546145.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
 db.Files.OrderBy(f => f.Expiry_date).ToList();
```

or

```
 db.Files.OrderByDescending(f => f.Expiry_date).ToList();
```

Comment: Add a leading line and also explain why your answer will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
return View(db.Files.OrderBy(col=>col.Expiry_date).ToList());
```

Or replace Expiry_date with any other column you want to sort on.